# Test if UITableViewCell has been deleted

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit

i have a simple question. I have a UITableView in which you can add and delete cells. If the first tableViewCell is deleted i want something else to happen. How could i test to see if the FIRST cell has been deleted via using an `if` statement?

```
if(//how do i test?)
{
//DO SOMETHING HERE!!
}
```

Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you already have a reference to the UITableViewCell that you are about to delete and the UITableView that it lives in. If so, just do

```
NSIndexPath indexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:deletedCell];
```

and look at indexPath.row to determine the row. Note that you'll have to do this prior to the cell actually being deleted/removed from the table view.

Comment: okay, if i created a UITableViewCell in my `cellForRow` method, could that be the reference you are talking about? And how would i put this into an `if` statement? Thanks a lot for the reply! :D

Comment: How are you deleting the cell in the first place? Presumably it has to involve a reference to the cell you are about to delete.

Comment: well, i call the `commitEditingStyle` method and inside i have
`if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        [[self cells] removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        [[self imageArray]removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        
        NSArray *indexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath];
        [[self myTableView] deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }`

Comment: i use that to delete the cell.

Comment: Great, so you **already have** the index path of the row you are deleting. Just check if `indexPath.row == 0` and that will tell you if it's the first cell or not.

Comment: right, but will that test to see if it has been deleted or not? because if it has been deleted, i want something else to happen. And thanks again for all of the help!